# Why are my textures pink? (Duplicatee)

Tags: rendering, texturing

So, I was trying to make an image for an online game, (ROBLOX). I understand fully how to do it, as I have done it in the first place. However, whenever I try to actually upload the 3D image into blender, the texture file does not show up and my entire character turns pink ( https://gyazo.com/49266465a404cba245453d766d6629ce ). I tried to search for the missing files, but it said there was an error. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Blender, but everything that I've tried hasn't worked. Also, whenever I go on Blender, I have to change the RGB from pink to black EVERY TIME.

Please help!

Comment: If you could add a link to your blend file, we could help you more easily. There are quite a few reasons why this might happen. Also are you using cycles or blender render?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to link the file, haha sorry I'm new to blender a bit. I'm using Blender Render.